# Copying one Excel Sheet for the whole year

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do this for the whole year for 2018 and when I run my code I get 2017 instead. Here is my code below

```
Sub MakeSheetForEachDay()
'Will copy the sheet named "START" and rename as
'as a date, 1-Jan, 2-Jan, etc.
'
    Dim wsStart As Worksheet
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim mth As Long, dy As Long

    Set wsStart = Sheets("START")
    For mth = 1 To 12
        For dy = 1 To Day(DateSerial(Year(2018), mth + 1, 1) - 1)
            strDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(2018), mth, dy), "ddd mmm d")
            wsStart.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = strDate
        Next dy
    Next mth
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer don't use `Year(2018)` just use `DateSerial(2018, mth + 1, 1)`

If you look at the [documentation for year](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88k2aec8(v=vs.90).aspx) you'll see it defined as

```
 Public Function Year(ByVal DateValue As DateTime) As Integer
```

This means when `Year(2018)` is evaluated it must convert the integer 2018 to a DateTime. It does this by adding 2018 days to the epoch which gives you 7/10/1905. So `Year(2018)` returns 1905.

It just so happens that `Format(DateSerial(2017, mth, dy), "ddd mmm d")` and  `Format(DateSerial(1905, mth, dy), "ddd mmm d")` return the same value because Jan, 1 1905 and 2017 were both Sundays. This is why you're confused by the output of `Format(DateSerial(Year(2018), mth, dy), "ddd mmm d")`